# Конечный URL редиректа

Tags: редирект, веб-программирование, php

Есть example.com, который иногда дает редирект на example1.com, а иногда на example2.com. Необходимо при помощи php "перейти" по example.com и узнать конечную ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. [опцию cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` и параметр `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` из [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php).